# Sending custom data with forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, controls

I have some radio-like control in a HTML form that looks like this:
[image]

Only one of these buttons can be depressed at once, but they're simply jQuery controlled `<div>`s.

How would I send the name of the button that is depressed with the form data? For example, `type=tiny`.

I assume I'd use jQuery, but is there any pitfalls to doing it with JavaScript? Will I need to hook the form submit event or something?
Thanks.

Comment: And why are they not Styled radio buttons?

Comment: @epascarello I didn't realize that was a thing. I'll look into it.

Comment: @epascarello I really don't know why I didn't consider this before. Please make your comment an answer and I will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn radio buttons into buttons, this is a quick idea

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb1" value="1"/><label for="rb1">One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" value="2" /><label for="rb2">Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb3"  value="3"/><label for="rb3">Three</label>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.buttons input {
    display:none;
}

.buttons input + label{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 2em;
    padding: .3em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.buttons input:checked + label{
    background-color: red;
}

.buttons input + label:hover{
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Mmsf2/